# IPC between Android and linux PC using TCP and adb forward, connect successfully but transfer empty data

Tags: android, linux, tcp, adb, ipc

I have been trying to do IPC (inter-process-communication) between my Android phone and Linux PC using tcp and adb, with an Android app as Client and a python-process on PC as Server.

My goal is to send a String (i.e. *laneInfoStr*) from Client to Server.

The problem is that the Server can accept connection from Client but receives empty string during data transfer.

## Implementation details

I do a adb port forwarding from Android to Linux as follow:

`$ adb reverse tcp:8888 tcp:8888`

Here is the core code on Client's side (on Android phone) to send *laneInfoStr*.

```
public void sendMessage() {
    Log.d("wlx", String.format("sending: %s", laneInfoStr));
    try (
         Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 8888)) {
        boolean connected = socket.isConnected(); 
        if (connected) {
            Log.d("wlx", "connected successfully");
        } else {
            Log.e("wlx", "failed to connect");
        }

        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out);
        output.println(laneInfoStr);
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        Log.d("wlx", "message sent successfully!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("wlx", "failed to send message!");
        Log.e("wlx", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I also create a new thread each time for sending message.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                sendMessage();
            }
        }).start();
```

And the python code for Server (on Linux PC):

```
import socket
import threading



def handle_client(client_socket):
    try:
        request = client_socket.recv(1024)
        print(f"received client's message: {request}")
        client_socket.send("hi from server".encode())
    except IOError:
        print("failed to read client socket or send message")
        client_socket.close()
    finally:
        client_socket.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bind_ip = "0.0.0.0" 
    bind_port = 8888  

    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    server.bind((bind_ip, bind_port))

    print("[*] Listening on %s:%d" % (bind_ip, bind_port))

    server.listen(5)
    while True:
        client, addr = server.accept()

        print("accepted connection from %s:%d" % (addr[0], addr[1]))

        client_handler = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client,))
        client_handler.start()
```

## What I tried:

I first start the Server and then the Client.

Client's log:

```
sending: 00,40
connected successfully
message sent successfully!
```

Server's log:

```
[*] Listening on 0.0.0.0:8888
accepted connection from 127.0.0.1:43823
received client's message: b''
```

The log “sending: 00,40” indicate that laneInfoStr is not empty.

The whole process throws no exception and reaches "message sent successfully!".

## What I expect

the Server receives message '00,40'
and the Server's log should be:

`received client's message: b'00,40\n'`

## What actually happens

the Server receive an EMPTY message b' '
with the log:

`received client's message: b''`

Comment: `new Socket("localhost", ...` Sorry but i do not believe that that would connect with s server on your pc.

Comment: `output.println(laneInfoStr)` Please show what you sent. Initiate that variable.

Comment: @blackapps but i have done adb port forwarding, expecting packets to localhost:8888 on Android will be forwarding to localhost:8888 on Linux PC.

Comment: @blackapps Log.d("wlx", String.format("sending: %s", laneInfoStr));  this line before Socket logprint the variable.  I believe the laneInfoStr variable itself is not the cause.

Comment: Ok. I dont understand why you would use adb to begin with. A client on your phone can just connect to a server on your pc without adb and port forwarding.

Comment: @blackapps I am new to this. Are there any other ways to do IPC via USB between Android and Linux PC?

Comment: `this line before Socket logprint the variable` Yes. But we cannot see the log so we dont know what the variable contains. Assign a value to it in code so we know.

Comment: You did not tell before that you used a USB connection. I assumed wifi.

Comment: @blackapps please check the "What I tried:" part, I show both the Client's and the Server's running log. The Client's log says "sending: 00,40", which means laneInfoStr when reaching that line is "00,40".

Comment: A socket.close() is missing.

Comment: `client_socket.send("hi from server".encode())` The client is not reading that message.

Comment: On Android side I would recommend to change `laneInfoStr` to a parameter of `sendMessage` method. Because of multi-threading `laneInfoStr` (which is a field?) can change at any time, so the log message `sending: ...` may print different data than the actual data that is sent.