# Send file from Android to Desktop using C# Xamarin via USB Cable

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am developing android app that can do file transfer with PC via USB, but I don't know how to write and implement it in my code.

Below is my code:

```
await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();
 var status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();
 if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
 {
     await DisplayAlert("Denied", "Permission to access was denied!", "Close");
 }
 else
 {
     var fileResult = await FilePicker.PickAsync();
     if (fileResult != null)
     {
         string filePath = fileResult.FullPath;
         // Proceed with file transfer
         try
         {
             File.Copy(filePath, "D:\\shared\\folder");
             await DisplayAlert("Success", "MEssage Success", "Close");
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             await DisplayAlert("Messgae", $"Error:" + ex.Message, "Close");
         }
     }
 }
```

Any suggestion is a big help. Thanks

Comment: Well, what is wrong with your code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77263452/ipc-between-android-and-linux-pc-using-tcp-and-adb-forward-connect-successfully

Comment: Android does not have access to drives or folder of the connected PC via USB. Therefore your code can only fail. You need software on both sides, one on the Android side sending the file and one on PC side receiving the file and saving it to disk.

Comment: ```File.Copy(filePath, "D:\\shared\\folder");```, the windows path can't read by android

Comment: @Robert, Thanks. But can you give me an example of this software to use. Also can ADB could help the process?

Comment: You always need some software on PC side to accept the files. An Android app alone does not work.